# read.table is returning a single column of "NA" characters under the heading ��D

Tags: r, encoding, na, read.table

I have encountered a very strange problem when trying to read a table of data into R using the read.table function. Rather than the actual data being read, I get a single column of NA characters under the heading ÿþD (which is not anywhere in my code or in my input file). My code and data file are below. Please let me know if you have any suggestions as to why I am getting this strange result. I have been searching for hours and come up with nothing.

code:

```
Raw_Annotation_data_AllDeer<-read.table("Sample.txt", as.is=TRUE, row.names=NULL, 
                                         check.names = TRUE, sep="\t", fill=T, header=T, 
                                         strip.white = T, quote = "", na.strings = "NA", 
                                         comment.char="")
```

File (first 5 lines):

```
Document_Name   Sequence_Name   Track_Name  Type    Name    Sequence    Minimum Min_(with_gaps) Maximum Max_(with_gaps) Length  Length_(with_gaps)  #_Intervals Direction   Average_Quality Coverage    modified_by Polymorphism_Type   Strand-Bias Strand-Bias_>50%_P-value    Strand-Bias_>65%_P-value    Variant_Frequency   Variant_Nucleotide(s)   Variant_P-Value_(approximate)
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10000_ARHGAP15  GAAAGAATCATTAACAGTTAGAAGTTGATG-AAGTTTCAATAACAAGTGGGCACTGAGAGAAAG    55916421    56019336    55916483    56019399    63  64  1   forward         User                            
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10001_ARHGAP15  GATACCACTGTACTATGCAGAAATCTACAAATTCTGATATCCCTGTGGAAACACTGAATCCCACCCGCCAAGGCACTGGAGCTGTGCAAATGAGAATCAAAAATGCCAACAGCCACCATGACAGGCTGAGCCAAAGTAAATCTATGATCCTCACCGAAGTTGGGAAGGTCACTGAACCT 55936395    56039336    55936573    56039514    179 179 1   forward         User                            
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10002_HNMT  CTGACACAATAATAATGAGAATCTTAGCATTGGTAGCTAAGAGACTATGGAAGAATTTCAGGGTAGCTGGGATGTCTTTAACATAATACAGCAT  61980947    62093615    61981040    62093708    94  94  1   forward         User                            
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10003_HNMT  CTGAATCATATGAATAAAGTCCCACCTCTGAAGTTCTTTTTTCTCCATCATTCTATTTTGATATTCAGATGATGTCTCTTTATGCCAAGCAAACTTTATGTTCTCAAGGTTTGATGTCTTTGCTACAAGCT 61986120    62098794    61986250    62098924    131 131 1   forward         User                            
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10004_HNMT  CTTTGTACTTGGTGATTTGTTCAGCACTTGGTTCAACAACTTCATTGATGATATGAACTCCTGGGTACTGAGCTTGCACTTTGGAGAGAATTTGAAGGTCAATTTCAC    61987773    62100453    61987880    62100560    108 108 1   forward         User
```

Comment: Please simply use `read.delim("Sample.txt")` and tell us what is the result

Comment: Hi Ali, I get an identical result

Comment: Try `read.delim("Sample.txt", check.names=F)`

Comment: You're going to have to supply the data somehow so that the tabs are preserved.  Otherwise nobody can duplicate what you are attempting to do.  I do not know if that is possible on SO.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: If you remove the sep='\t' it seems to be read OK. Although the columns at the end are NA's because it has fewer values in the rows than there are columns. I'm thinking an encoding problem or mismatched quote.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by 'encoding problem' and 'mismatched quotes'?

Comment: The strange characters suggests possibly an encoding problem, meaning that your system locale is set to something other than it should be. But as others have pointed out, it is very difficult to diagnose these problems without the ability to replicate it completely, which would require an exact copy of the file (with tabs). You might at least consider editing your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

The "#"  (comment.char) in the header row might be problematic if it were in the data. But check.names() seems to have caught it. This "works" (after removal of the `sep="\t"`:

```
Raw_Annotation_data_AllDeer<-read.table(text="Document_Name   Sequence_Name   Track_Name  Type    Name    Sequence    Minimum Min_(with_gaps) Maximum Max_(with_gaps) Length  Length_(with_gaps)  #_Intervals Direction   Average_Quality Coverage    modified_by Polymorphism_Type   Strand-Bias Strand-Bias_>50%_P-value    Strand-Bias_>65%_P-value    Variant_Frequency   Variant_Nucleotide(s)   Variant_P-Value_(approximate)
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10000_ARHGAP15  GAAAGAATCATTAACAGTTAGAAGTTGATG-AAGTTTCAATAACAAGTGGGCACTGAGAGAAAG    55916421    56019336    55916483    56019399    63  64  1   forward         User                            
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10001_ARHGAP15  GATACCACTGTACTATGCAGAAATCTACAAATTCTGATATCCCTGTGGAAACACTGAATCCCACCCGCCAAGGCACTGGAGCTGTGCAAATGAGAATCAAAAATGCCAACAGCCACCATGACAGGCTGAGCCAAAGTAAATCTATGATCCTCACCGAAGTTGGGAAGGTCACTGAACCT 55936395    56039336    55936573    56039514    179 179 1   forward         User                            
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10002_HNMT  CTGACACAATAATAATGAGAATCTTAGCATTGGTAGCTAAGAGACTATGGAAGAATTTCAGGGTAGCTGGGATGTCTTTAACATAATACAGCAT  61980947    62093615    61981040    62093708    94  94  1   forward         User                            
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10003_HNMT  CTGAATCATATGAATAAAGTCCCACCTCTGAAGTTCTTTTTTCTCCATCATTCTATTTTGATATTCAGATGATGTCTCTTTATGCCAAGCAAACTTTATGTTCTCAAGGTTTGATGTCTTTGCTACAAGCT 61986120    62098794    61986250    62098924    131 131 1   forward         User                            
Chr2_FT Chr2    Chr2.bed    CDS 10004_HNMT  CTTTGTACTTGGTGATTTGTTCAGCACTTGGTTCAACAACTTCATTGATGATATGAACTCCTGGGTACTGAGCTTGCACTTTGGAGAGAATTTGAAGGTCAATTTCAC    61987773    62100453    61987880    62100560    108 108 1   forward         User                            ", as.is=TRUE, row.names=NULL, check.names = TRUE, fill=T, header=T, strip.white = T, quote = "", na.strings = "NA", comment.char="")
```

Comment: I find that the code works if all the lines containing 'missing' data are removed, even though these lines still contain tab characters to indicate the columns that have been left empty. The fill=T part of the code should have dealt with this. Any ideas about why the code is not working when it encounters empty cells?

Comment: My earlier comment makes about 50% sense. I was finding ctrl-I characters using a regex pattern of `\u0009` but for some reason the editor was not interpreting `\t` as tab, despite its promise to do so.

Comment: I have tried adding NA characters to all the empty cells, but I still get the same column of uninformative data.

Comment: Try reading the data with Firefox and then seeing what encoding it reports. I have found that Firefox is more capable to auto-detecting encodings. Sometimes UTF-16 gives very screwy results because UTF-8 is the default (on some systems, anyway).

Comment: I upvoted your comment so that it will display when the next person comes along to read this transcript. You could save other SO-ers time by checkmarking either this answer or write one yourself that describes more fully how you solved your problem.